# R function to act on sequential rows in a data frame adding a label if a certain condition is met

Tags: r

I have a data frame that is in this format:

```
df<-data.frame(A=(c(4,1,5,4)), B=(c(4,2,4,5)), C=(c(7, 2, 3,5)), D=(c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 1", "Group 2")))
```

I would like to write a function that searches through each row of the data frame and if it finds a value <=3 with a Group 1 assignment, adds a fifth column with the string "Success"; if it does not find a value <=3 in any of the rows with a Group 1 assignment, it adds a fifth column with the string "Fail".

I then need to deploy this function over a similarly formatted data frame which has 36 columns and 1000 rows.

Comment: What do you want to do with the "Group 2" rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to ignore "Group 2" rows, then

```
df$Result<-ifelse(df$D=="Group 1", 
    ifelse(rowSums(df[,1:3]<=3)>0, "Success", "Fail"),
NA)
df
```

will return

```
  A B C       D  Result
1 4 4 7 Group 1    Fail
2 1 2 2 Group 2    <NA>
3 5 4 3 Group 1 Success
4 4 5 5 Group 2    <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a solution with a loop:

```
for(r in 1:nrow(df)){

  if (any(df[r, 1:3]<=3) & df[r,4] == 'Group 1') df [r, "E"] <- "Success"
  if (all(df[r, 1:3]>3) & df[r,4] == 'Group 1') df [r, "E"] <- "Fail"

}
```

You can put there more conditions, for example something for group 2